# iOS design pattern for parsing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a simple app that parses some cached instagram json. I only having two views 1. an uiCollectionView view with thumbnails of the images and 2. a modal view that shows a larger image along with some other instagram info (user, location, etc) once the user taps the thumbnail.

There are a lot of tutorials explaining collection views and parsing json, but I am having a hard time finding how to put it all together. I was thinking having classes for: the collection view, the modal view, and one for parsing the json.

Is that best practice? Should I add a class that keeps track of each instance of the instagram data (container holding the image and user data)? Should I use a singleton to have access the instagram data across every class?

Any design advice or links are appreciated! Happy Holidays

Comment: iOS != IOS (just like Apple isn't Cisco.)

Comment: @H2CO3 No way - are you serious? I thought Cisco was Spanish for Apple and IOS was stupid for iOS shows what I know :-P

Comment: @Popeye :D [15 chars]

Comment: Who knows, maybe Cisco made a knockoff version of UIKit with lowercase prefixes too.  They do own the IOS trademark after all.  Also, it's a bit hard to tell what you're asking.  Perhaps you could give us a little more detail, maybe some code?

Comment: @Popeye: If you were being serious, cisco doesn't mean apple in spanish. Apple in spanish is actually Manzana. Just so you know.

Comment: @JosueEspinosa haha no I wasn't being serious. I was just joking with `H2CO3` I didn't know that Apple in Spanish was actually Manzana so I have learned something :-)

Answer (score 0):

For parsing JSON now I would guess all the cool kids are using javascript core to do the parsing.

```
JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
JSValue *result = [context evaluateScript: @"{ someJSON: 'string' }"];
```

You can then pull the result out as a dictionary or array.

Comment: I think they're more likely still using `NSJSONSerialization`. It's just less code.